# ${{\left( 1-p \right)}^{n}}{{\text{ }}_{1}}{{F}_{1}}\left( n+1,n+a+1,\lambda T \right)\approx ?$

Tags: special-functions, approximation

I am trying to approximate 
$$\frac{p\left( n+a,\bar\lambda T \right){{\left( 1-p \right)}^{n}}_{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( n+1,n+a+1,\lambda T \right)}{p\left( n+a,\bar\lambda T \right)}={{\left( 1-p \right)}^{n}}{{\text{ }}_{1}}{{F}_{1}}\left( n+1,n+a+1,\lambda T \right)$$

If I use the asymptotic behavior of confluent function, I can rewrite it as:

$${{\left( 1-p \right)}^{n}}{{\text{ }}_{1}}{{F}_{1}}\left( n+1,n+a+1,\lambda T \right)\approx \frac{b\left( n+a,a,p \right)}{p\left( a,\lambda T \right){{p}^{a}}}$$

That didn't help me, but maybe gives you an idea.

I could rewrite numerator differently so that I get the following ratio:
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{p\left( n+a+k,\bar\lambda T \right)}b\left( n+k,k,p \right)}{p\left( n+a,\bar\lambda T \right)}$$
It didn't help me either but i though it might give you an idea.

when $(n>0)$ $(a>0)$ $(0<p<1)$ $(\bar\lambda>\lambda)$
$$b\left( n+k,k,p \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   n+k  \\
   k  \\
\end{matrix} \right){{\left( p \right)}^{k}}{{\left( 1-p \right)}^
{n}}$$
$$p\left( n+a,\lambda T \right)=\frac{{{e}^{-\lambda T}}{{\left( \lambda T \right)}^{n+a}}}{\left( n+a \right)!}$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the asymptotics you are looking for? $n\rightarrow\infty$? $\lambda T\rightarrow\infty$? or something else?

Comment: Thanks O.L. I worked on my problem and I could get rid of one layer of complication. I posted another question, where I need to write Poisson tail with rate $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ in terms of each process separately. I would appreciate your opinion on that.